# VBA Email range to photo in loop keeps pasting the first image in the second iteration

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, office365

Hello guys I have this code that is inside a loop that sends Emails, it paste the first range to Photo in the body of the email good but in the second iteration the code pastes the first range copied.
can you guys help me out thanks in advance

Heres the Full Code, the sub PendnewSS calls the createPNG code in order to paste the image in the HTML body of the email

```vb
Sub pendnewSS()
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Remove Sheet if exists--------------------------------------------------------------------

Dim s As String: s = "Template"
Dim startingCell As Range
Dim datarange As Range
Dim selectedrange As Range

Dim Mails As New Dictionary

    ' the destination i want to send
   

If exists(s) Then
Worksheets("Template").Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Else
Worksheets.Add After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Template"
End If

'arrays for destinations----------------------------------------------------------------------


Sheets("BD").Select

Dim arr As Variant
Dim dest, destSS As Variant
Dim Expo As Variant
Dim plants As Variant
Dim res As Variant
Dim lscol As Long
Dim myRange As Range
Dim dias As String
Dim mayorque As String
dias = Hoja3.Range("D2").Value
    mayorque = ">=" & dias

arr = Hoja8.ListObjects("BD").DataBodyRange.Value
destSS = Array("Destinations")
plants = Array("Plants")
                
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

'filter per loaded and actual plc ------------------------------------------------------------

    Hoja8.ListObjects("BD").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
    "L", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Hoja8.ListObjects("BD").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
    "Actual Plc", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Hoja8.ListObjects("BD").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
    mayorque, Operator:=xlFilterValues
'loop for each destination ,fliters it and select the data-------------------------------------

For Each dest In destSS

    Hoja8.ListObjects("BD").Range.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:= _
        Array(dest), Operator:=xlFilterValues
With Hoja8.ListObjects("BD").Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("BD[Load Status]"), Order:=xlDescending
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("BD[Destination]"), Order:=xlAscending
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("BD[Current Location]"), Order:=xlAscending
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("BD[Event]"), Order:=xlAscending
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("BD[Dwell]"), Order:=xlDescending
    .Apply
End With
    
    On Error Resume Next
Set myRange = Hoja8.ListObjects("BD").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If myRange Is Nothing Then

'Do nothing

Else
Set startingCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Range("B28")
Set datarange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Range(startingCell, startingCell.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
    If Not IsEmpty(startingCell.Value) Then
        datarange.ClearContents
        Else
        
        End If


    'do stuff
    Sheets("BD").Activate
        Range("A1").Select
        With Hoja8.ListObjects("BD")
          Union(.ListColumns(1).Range, _
            .ListColumns(3).Range, _
            .ListColumns(5).Range, _
            .ListColumns(8).Range, _
            .ListColumns(10).Range, _
            .ListColumns(15).Range, _
            .ListColumns(17).Range, _
            .ListColumns(19).Range).Select
    
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Template").Select
'check ifs there any data in the sheet and if there are, find the last row to paste the data--------------


        startingCell.Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        
       'Selection.Paste
        Dim last As Long
        Dim pt, pt2 As PivotTable
        Dim PlanFilter As PivotField
        Dim NewPlan As String
        Dim color As Range
        Set pt = Worksheets("pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable10")
        Set pt2 = Worksheets("pivot").PivotTables("Units")
        Set PlanFilter = pt.PivotFields("Terminal")
        NewPlan = dest

        'Update and refresh the PIVOT table
        With pt
            .PivotFields("Terminal").ClearAllFilters
            .PivotFields("Terminal").CurrentPage = NewPlan
            .RefreshTable
        End With
         With pt2
            .PivotFields("Terminal").ClearAllFilters
            .PivotFields("Terminal").CurrentPage = NewPlan
            .RefreshTable
        End With
                              
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template")
        ws.Activate
        last = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
        Set color = ws.Range("B28:I" & last)
        color.Select
        
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = _
        xlConditionValueLowestValue
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
        .color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = _
        xlConditionValuePercentile
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor
        .color = RGB(255, 128, 0)
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = _
        xlConditionValueHighestValue
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
        .color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

'mail
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookMail As Object
    Dim strTempFilePath As String
    Dim strTempFileName As String
    Dim Rango As Range
    Dim TablaRango As Range
    Dim outmail As Outlook.MailItem
      
        'Name it anything, doesn't matter
    strTempFileName = "RangeAsPNG"
    ' range that i want as image
    Set Rango = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Range("A1:J27")
    ' Range as table
    Set TablaRango = ws.Range("B28:I" & last)
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutlookMail
        .To = Mails(dest)
        
            'Create the range as a PNG file and store it in temp folder
        Call createPNG(Rango, strTempFileName)
                'Embed the image in Outlook
        strTempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\" & strTempFileName & ".png"
        .Attachments.Add strTempFilePath, olByValue, 0
        
        .Subject = "Mail" & dest
        .HTMLBody = "Hello <br><br>" & _
                    "<img src='cid:" & strTempFileName & ".png' style='border:0'><br><br>" & _
                    "Heres the table<br>" & RangetoHTML(TablaRango)
        .Display '
    End With
        


             

        
End With
        Set myRange = Nothing
        Set datarange = Nothing
        Set startingCell = Nothing
        Set Rango = Nothing
     End If
Next


 


Call SortDB



 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

```vb
Sub createPNG(ByRef Rango As Range, nameFile As String)

    Dim wksName As String

    wksName = Rango.Parent.Name
    'Delete the existing PNG file of same name, if exists
    On Error Resume Next
        Kill Environ$("temp") & "\" & nameFile & ".png"
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Copy the range as picture
    Rango.CopyPicture
    
    'Paste the picture in Chart area of same dimensions
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wksName).ChartObjects.Add(Rango.Left, Rango.Top, Rango.Width, Rango.Height)
        .Activate
        .Chart.Paste
        'Export the chart as PNG File to Temp folder
        .Chart.Export Environ$("temp") & "\" & nameFile & ".png", "PNG"
    End With
    
    Worksheets(wksName).ChartObjects(Worksheets(wksName).ChartObjects.Count).Delete
    

End Sub
```

i used the

`Application.CutCopyMode = False` with no effect

Comment: Hard to talk about a loop without seeing it. How is `rango` changing as you loop?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad here's part of the loop

```With OutlookMail
        .To = Correos(dest) 'this is the array
        Call createPNG(Rango, strTempFileName)
        'Embed the image in Outlook
        strTempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\" & strTempFileName & ".png"
        .Attachments.Add strTempFilePath, olByValue, 0
        .Subject = & dest
        .HTMLBody =```

Comment: FYI you could put `.Delete` as the last line in that `With` block and remove the line below.

Comment: Please *edit your question* and add code there - too difficult to read in a comment.  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77054057/edit    And show the *whole loop*

Comment: @TimWilliams Did it, still paste the last range :(

Comment: Was not intended as a fix - just cleaner

Comment: `Set Rango = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Range("A1:J27")` it's always the same range?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes sir! just changes de data inside of it

Comment: I only see you pasting to B28?

Comment: yes that's the other range that contains a "table", the email is as follows:

greeting message
Pasted Image (Rango)
Pasted Table ( TablaRango) in B28

Comment: So what part of the loop is updating A1:J27 ?

Comment: @TimWilliams i just put it inside the loop, how can i do that?